# Extjs 5 grid sync row render issues

Tags: extjs

using extjs 5.1.0
My issues, when I add value to store of grid and then call store.sync()
inserted row become selected (visually) but I cannot select it for edit or darg&drop row for sorting, only helps reload grid.

here is my store:

```
    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
        model: 'pbxe.module.conference.ConferenceModel',

        proxy: {
            type: 'direct',
            api: {
               read:    pbxe._conference.read, 
               create:  pbxe._conference.create, 
               update:  pbxe._conference.update, 
               destroy: pbxe._conference.destroy, 
            },
            reader: {
                rootProperty: 'data',
                totalProperty: 'totalCount',
                successProperty: 'success',
                messageProperty: 'message'
            },      
            writer: {
                writeAllFields: true,
            },
        },
        autoSync: false,
        autoLoad: true,

    });
```

Comment: Can you post a fiddle?

Comment: Sencha fiddle is here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ran into same problem, seems there is an issue of the Selection Model keeping a map of the records added to the store which can't get "deselected".

So with a bit of brute force:

```js
// WORKAROUND for grid  / selection model problem 
// after adding multiple new records with Store.sync()
//var grid = grid bound to this store...
myStore.sync(
  {
    scope: this,
    success: function (batch, options) {
  var sm = grid.getSelectionModel();
  var records = batch.operations[0].getRecords();
  if (sm && sm.selected) 
  { // deselect does not work as has bug leaves new records in map
    sm.selected.map = {}; //wipe clear the selected records map
  }
  sm.select(records);
    }
  });
```

Hope this helps - works for us in Ext JS 5.1.0